# Hacking the phprenderer, helpers throwing errors

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a route which I use to create caches `updatePostCaches`.  I was making curl calls back to my application, saving the output, compressing it, and writing it to my cache dir.  The problem is that it is very slow because it has to keep loading my whole application over and over again.  I have used the phprenderer in another context, but it never required helpers such as `'translate'`.

```
    $this->renderer = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
    $this->resolver = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver();
    $this->renderer->setResolver($this->resolver);

    $this->renderer->getHelperPluginManager()->setServiceLocator($serviceLocator);

    //This one DID resolve an error about getting 'rootLocationJson', but I feel like I shouldn't even have to do this
    $this->renderer->getHelperPluginManager()->setFactory('rootLocationJson', \Location\View\Helper\LocationFactory::class);

    //Even this doesn't work
    $this->renderer->getHelperPluginManager()-> setFactory('translate', 'Zend\I18n\View\Helper\Translate');

    $this->rootLocations = $this->om->getRepository(\Location\Entity\Location::class)->findBy(array('parent' => null));

    //Also wish I didn't have to do this
    $this->resolver->add(
        array(
            'layout' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../../Application/view/layout/layout.phtml'),
            'index' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../../Cache/view/cache/index/index.phtml'),
            'post' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../../Cache/view/cache/index/post.phtml'),
            'location' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../../Cache/view/cache/index/location.phtml'),
        )
    );

    $viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel($vars);
    $viewModel->setTemplate($view);

    $layout = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel(array('content' => $this->renderer->render($viewModel)));
    $layout->setTemplate('layout');


    $output = $this->renderer->render($layout);
```

After the last line I get the following error: `Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for 'translate'`

I feel like I'm just doing this wrong.  Someone suggested I use the currently-instantiated phprenderer but that would poison it because again, this is the phprenderer of a different request that will still eventually need to be rendered.

Comment: I don't see any problem in using the renderer instance as was suggested to you. You should be able to use the same renderer instance for different render jobs without problems. What problems do you expect when you are talking about "poisoning"?

Comment: @Wilt I'll be changing the templates at the very least.

Comment: Trying it, though.

Comment: Can you not register those templates with their own unique names inside the existing template map? Then you can skip overwriting the existing template map resolver...

Comment: It's not that, that I'm afraid of.  In fact, if I can use the renderer like you suggest, then I can just truncate all those definitions and use the ones already defined.  I'm afraid of overwriting the phprenderers current state that will eventually render when my controller exits.

Comment: It actually did work because I'm returning a JsonModel.  It works!!!  Thanks!

Comment: No need to worry about that, the renderer is not caching or storing anything...

Comment: Wow.  I went from several seconds down to mere milliseconds.  That should scale much better.  Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe good to answer and close the question. Seems like you solved it.